# How to inspect a dimension in SBERT embeddings

Tags: transformer, embeddings

I am using SBERT transformers to vectorize text. I want to use the sentence embeddings in a linear regression to predict a value or a classification. Some dimensions are highly colinear and result in a matrix close to non-invertible: 34 and 688 have 97% correlation, and each has 81% correlation to 756. For now, and for safety, I exclude those dimensions from the matrix, but I would like to understand the problem and the data, and possibly ferret out bugs.

How can I know what those dimensions relate to?